# Jquery и динамический value

Tags: jquery

Добавляю форму ввода

```
$('#performer_name_field').append(form_name1+form_name2+form_name3+form_button);
```

form_name1 имеет id=name1

Как получить результат ввода данных в поле #name1.value при нажатии на кнопку оправки результата?

Поиграть с .on?

```
$(document).on("click", "#performer_name_field_button", function(event){
        alert(123);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем сложность, собственно? http://jsfiddle.net/t2tXW/

Comment: у шайтан. Вешал на onclick, а там уже .on. Естественно не работало. Спасибо.